# decode large base64 from xml in java: OutOfMemory

Tags: java, xml, file-io, base64, out-of-memory

I need to write a base64 encoded element of an xml file into a separate file. Problem: the file could easily reach the size of 100 MB. Every solution I tried ended with the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". The problem is not reading the xml in general or the decoding process, but the size of the base64 block.

I used jdom, dom4j and XMLStreamReader to access the xml file. However, as soon as I want to access the base64 content of the respective element I get the mentioned error. I also tried an xslt using saxon's base64Binary-to-octets function, but of course with the same result.

Is there a way to stream this base64 encoded part into a file without getting the whole chunk in one single piece?

Thanks for your hints,

Andreas

Comment: If the file could only reach 100MB, then you can certainly fit it in RAM on an almost-modern desktop. Passing `-Xmx500m` to the JVM would do it.

Comment: increase your heap size? or are you on a machine with 128mb ram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the StAX API ([tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaXML/article.html)). For large text elements, you should get several text events which you need to push into a streaming Base64 implementation (like the one skaffman mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for all your posts, a mix of all the hints did it. I had StAX implemented in the meanwhile. However, I also had to replace an old version of commons-codec to get the Base64OutputStream.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has a [`Base64OutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html), which should allow you to feed the XML data in a scalable way, by chaining the `Base64OutputStream` with a `FileOutputStream`.

You'll need a representation of the XML as a String, so you may not even have to read it into a DOM structure at all.

Something like:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(
   new Base64OutputStream(
      new BufferedOutputStream(
         new FileOutputStream("/path/to/my/file")
      )
   )
);
printWriter.write(myXml);
printWriter.close();
```

If the input XML file is too big, then you should read chunks of it into a buffer in a loop, writing the buffer contents to the output (i.e. a standard reader-to-writer copy).

Comment: This will encode to Base64, does not decode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any XML api would let you access an element's text as a stream rather than a String. If the String is 100 MB, then your only option is probably to change the JVM's heap size until you don't have any OutOfMemoryError :

```
java -Xmx256m your.class.Name
```

Comment: This seems to be incorrect.  See my question (and answer) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400128/obtain-inputstream-from-xml-element-content.

Answer (score 0):

If your file can get that big, never use a DOM parser. Use a simple SAX approach to access the data elements, and stream the base64 data into `Base64OutputStream` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As [lbruder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434817/lbruder) said, use a SAX parser to read the document in a streaming fashion. If you use [Base64OutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html) then you have to set the flag to let it DECODE instead of the default ENCODE. You also have to convert the char array from the characters callback to a byte array before passing it to the outputstream, needing additional memory allocations and copies.

I wrote an alternative base64 decoder for exactly this usecase, it is available at [github](https://github.com/jhorstmann/Base64/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jhorstmann/base64/Base64StreamDecoder.java). Here is an example on how to use it:

```
Base64StreamDecoder decoder = new Base64StreamDecoder();
OutputStream out;

...

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
    decoder.reset();
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(...));
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
    decoder.checkComplete();
    out.close();
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
    decoder.decode(ch, start, length, out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jörn, for this link. As I was already using commons-codec I was happy to continue with that. I'm sure others might find your library very helpful, though.