# Obtain InputStream from XML element content

Tags: java, xml, stream, sax

My servlet's doPost() receives an HttpServletRequest whose ServletInputStream sends me a large chunk of uuencoded data wrapped in XML.  E.g., there is an element:

```
<filedata encoding="base64">largeChunkEncodedHere</filedata>
```

I need to decode the chunk and write it to a file. I would like to get an InputStream from the chunk, decode it as a stream using MimeUtility, and use that stream to write the file---I would prefer not to read this large chunk into memory.

The XML is flat; i.e., there is not much nesting.  My first idea is to use a SAX parser but I don't know how to do the hand-off to a stream to read just the chunk.

Thanks for your ideas.

Glenn

**Edit 1:** Note JB Nizet's pessimistic answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832123/decode-large-base64-from-xml-in-java-outofmemory).

**Edit 2:** I've answered my own question affirmatively below, and marked maximdim's answer below as correct, even though it doesn't quite answer the question, it did direct me to the StAX API and Woodstox.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to accomplish. If you're using Streams properly the data should not be kept in memory at the same time. On the other hand, I don't think it would matter in your case as browser/client would probably submit whole data in POST to your servlet before you will get a chance to handle it so it shouldn't matter much as whole data will be already in memory on your side.

Comment: @maximdim The question is about using streams properly.  Using twice as much memory makes a difference in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SAX filter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipsaxfilter/) or XPath to get only element(s) you're interested in. Once you have content of your element, pass it to [MimeUtility.decode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decode%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) and write stream to file.

I suggest you update your question with code sample and let us know what doesn't work.

**Update:**

Here is sample code using StaX2 parser (Woodstox). For some reason StaX parser included in JDK doesn't seems to have comparable getText() method, at least at quick glance.

Obviously input (r) and output (w) could be any Reader/Writer or Stream - using String just for example here.

```
    Reader r = new StringReader("<foo><filedata encoding=\"base64\">largeChunkEncodedHere</filedata></foo>");
    Writer w = new StringWriter();

    XMLInputFactory2 xmlif = (XMLInputFactory2)XMLInputFactory2.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader2 sr = (XMLStreamReader2)xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(r);

    boolean flag = false;
    while (sr.hasNext()) {
        sr.next();
        if (sr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
            if ("filedata".equals(sr.getLocalName())) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        else if (sr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) {
            if (flag) {
                sr.getText(w, false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(w);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look at that, but it seems that a "SAX filter" does not return a stream---which is the point of this question.  The question is not what is wrong with the existing code (there is none), but what is the code that should be written?

Comment: OK, I have posted quick code sample for you using StaX2 parser

Comment: Thanks, while this didn't get into the nitty-gritty of how it's done, it did point me in the right direction.  I've put details into my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion wrt Woodstox: it can also decode that base64 encoded stuff from within, efficiently. To do that, you need to cast `XMLStreamReader` into `XMLStreamReader2` (or `TypedXMLStreamReader`), which is part of Stax2 extension API.

But with that, you get methods `readElementAsBinary()` and `getElementAsBinary()` which automatically handle Base64 decoding. `XMLStreamWriter2` similarly has Base64-encoding methods for writing binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some details on how streaming from an element while parsing
with StAX is possible, using the [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) framework.

There is a good overview in [this article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84523/stax-the-odds-with-woodstox/).

From XMLInputFactory we can call createXMLStreamReader(java.io.InputStream
stream) using the ServletInputStream.  This returns an XMLStreamReader2, which
has a getText(Writer w, boolean preserveContents) method that returns an int for
the number of bytes written.  This method must be implemented.  In the
implementation Stax2ReaderImpl there is this implementation

```
// // // StAX2, Pass-through text accessors
public int getText(Writer w, boolean preserveContents)
    throws IOException, XMLStreamException
{
    char[] cbuf = getTextCharacters();
    int start = getTextStart();
    int len = getTextLength();

    if (len > 0) {
        w.write(cbuf, start, len);
    }
    return len;
}
```

In this code we will need to change the getTextCharacters() method so that it
reads from the InputStream.  In the Woodstox tests TestGetSegmentedText
testSegmentedGetCharacters() method we see a sr.getTextCharacters(offset, buf,
start, len) method used.  In fact the javadoc for the multiple argument
XMLStreamReader.getTextCharacters() shows the following implementation.

```
int length = 1024;
char[] myBuffer = new char[ length ];
for ( int sourceStart = 0 ; ; sourceStart += length ) {
    int nCopied = stream.getTextCharacters( sourceStart, myBuffer, 0, length );
    if (nCopied < length) {
        break;
    }
}
```